# how to configure redis sentinel log file location

Tags: redis

I have got the sentinel running across hosts, but unable to find the log location.
As per redis documentation : http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/sentinel.conf the conf file has no logging information.

1. How can i enable logging for sentinel?

Comment: add the following item to your configuration file: `logfile "path/to/file.log"`

Comment: Thanks for_stack. It worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following line to your configuration file (`/etc/redis-sentinel.conf`):

```
logfile "/var/log/redis/redis-sentinel.log"
```

Next, you can see the logs:

```
tail -f /var/log/redis/redis-sentinel.log
```